# Speed up web scraping on Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I am testing out on web scraping using Yahoo Finance using python with beautifulsoup lib but it's running very slow. How can I speed it up? and is it legal to scrape the site?

```
quotes = []
quote = {}
symbolList = ['SPY', 'AAPL']
    
for symbol in symbolList:
    url = ('http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%s?p=%s' % (symbol, symbol))
    page = requests.get(url)
    html = page.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    span_latest_price = soup.find("span", {"class": "Trsdu(0.3s) Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(b)"})
    span_quote_name = soup.find('h1', {'class': 'D(ib) Fz(16px) Lh(18px)'})

    last_price = span_latest_price.text if span_latest_price else ''
    name = span_quote_name.text if span_quote_name else ''
    quote = {'name': name, 'lastPrice': last_price}
    quotes.append(quote)
```

Comment: Scraping in general is a heavy task. Maybe take a look at Alpha Vantage, they offer API to access real time data for free. You can make 6 calls per minute with a free account.

Comment: @SarhadSalam Yes I have tried Alpha Vantage as well. It's 5 calls per minute for free account. Which is not sufficient when I need to update the price on some fixed interval

Comment: If you're updating prices once per day, or once per week, you can introduce sort of a sleep method after every 5 calls, and sleep for 15s and start another call.

Comment: @SarhadSalam I need query stock in batch. Alpha vantage does offer batch request for US stocks, but not global quotes tho.

Comment: @ping give [iex](https://github.com/addisonlynch/iexfinance) a try. That's a link to my Python wrapper for it. You can batch request for up to 50 symbols at once.